# Applying Images to Downloaded Model

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, objects, .fbx

I just downloaded a file from TurboSquid called 2014 NASCAR toyota. It was made in 3ds Max, but I want to work with it in blender so I downloaded the FBX file. Blender was unable to open it because it was an ASCII FBX file, so I used FBXConverter to change it to a binary FBX file. Following that conversion, Blender was able to open that file, and the model looks great! However, the object had no color, so I had to UV unwrap it. The problem is, the UV unwrap doesn't fit the texture very well. Here are some images to explain:
[image]
[image]

SO how do I go about properly unwrapping this? There are so many components for model, will I have to go through each one, unwrap it, and resize it to the texture map? Here is what the files of the texture maps look like: [image]

So am I supposed to just add these in as materials and then UV unwrap each part of the model? Thats seems difficult and probably not the fastest way to do it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: When searching on the site for this vehicle, there are five models available. 3 of these 5 have other file formats notable .obj. If you are provided this format then you should also have a corresponding .mtl file that will work on import. So at the very least you have a 3 in 5 chance of finding an automatic process to get these textures onto the model.

Comment: Your model should already be unwrapped, and UV coordinates present, no need to do it again. All you have to do is **create new materials**, and assign these textures into those materials using the availabe UV coordinates

Comment: Thanks for this comment, but I do not think the UV coordinates are present. When I unwrap the object, the textures do not line up well with the unwrapped model. It seem's really hard to align the model to the textures layout, any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: If the model has different texture maps consisting of islands it means it was unwrapped when texturing was done. Probably it was lost while converting. Reunwrapping it in order to fit the textures is a hard and long way while still possible (you'll need to have some unwrapping experience).

Answer (score 0):

Select the object and it's faces in edit mode and press 'U'. This will bring up the UV mapping window. 
Select Unwrap. 
In the UV editor window click on image > open image.

For a more details take a look at this great tutorial: https://cgi.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-low-poly-ninja-game-character-using-blender-part-2--cg-16133
(starting at step 17)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however my problem is not with unwrapping the object but rather fixing the object to the texture.. When I unwrap the object, the textures do not line up well with the unwrapped model. It seem's really hard to align the model to the textures layout, any suggestions on how to fix that? I updated the question to show the issue.